# Convert int to const wchar_t*

Tags: c++

As the title indicates I want to know the best way to convert an `int` to a `const wchar_t*`.
in fact I want to use the `_tcscpy` function

```
_tcscpy(m_reportFileName, myIntValue);
```

Comment: Normal typecast? But you remember that the "last" character _has_ to be zero, or you enter the territory of undefined behavior. This means your `int` can only store one character (`int` is 32 bits on Windows, and `wchar_t` is 16 bits).

Comment: I think (const wchar_t*)variable_name; should work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert"? Care to give an example?

Comment: Use a `std::wstring` and use `std::wostringstream` to capture the `int`.

Comment: Why do you want to use that function? That's not what it is used for!

Comment: @hmjd Or use [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, better again (forgot about that).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using a **C approach** (I'm assuming that `m_reportFileName` is a *raw* C `wchar_t` array), you may want to consider just **`swprintf_s()`** directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for swprintf_s, wprintf

int main()
{
    int myIntValue = 20;
    wchar_t m_reportFileName[256];

    swprintf_s(m_reportFileName, L"%d", myIntValue);

    wprintf(L"%s\n", m_reportFileName);
}
```

In a more modern **C++ approach**, you may consider using `std::wstring` instead of the raw `wchar_t` array and [**`std::to_wstring`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the conversion.

Comment: Isn't second parameter to `swprintf_s` supposed to be the size of the buffer?

Comment: @CinCout In C++, thanks to template tricks, the compiler is able to automatically deduce the buffer size from the first buffer argument.

Comment: @CinCout Have you considered try it with a compiler before asking here?

Comment: Obviously. It failed. Hence, the comment.

Comment: Obviously, it's a good thing that you get a compiler error when you try to fetch the _size of a pointer_ to a buffer (instead of the size of the buffer).

Comment: So if the first parameter is a buffer (not pointer) an overload exists?

Comment: @CinCout Yes. For buffers in C++ it automatically deduces the size.

Answer (score 7):

In `C++11`:

```
wstring value = to_wstring(100);
```

Pre-`C++11`:

```
wostringstream wss;
wss << 100;
wstring value = wss.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a "conversion". It's a two-step process:

1. Format the number into a string, using wide characters.
2. Use the address of the string in the call.

The first thing can be accomplished using e.g. [`StringCbPrintf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), assuming you're building with wide characters enabled.

Of course, you can opt to format the string straight into `m_reportFileName`, removing the need to do the copy altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If using wstring, might consider the below:

```
  int ValInt = 20;
  TCHAR szSize[20];

_stprintf(szSize, _T("%d"), ValInt);

wstring myWchar;
myWchar = (wstring)szSize;
```